# How to display a specific page number of a views mini pager?

Tags: 7, views, paging

I'm displaying a view on a pager with a mini pager. It has total number 15 pages.

I want to display page number 5 by default. The the next link will point to page number 6 and the previous link will point to page number 4.

I have tried the below code.

```
function mymodule_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
  $view->query->pager->current_page = 5;
}
```

It just moves the page number in the page number, displaying it as `page 5 of 15` but the views displaying the results of the page 1.

It it possible to set the default page number of a pager? How?
I'm using ajax in views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. I'm sharing here the solution.

I used the following code and it worked.

```
function mymodule_views_pre_build(&$view) {
  $view->set_current_page(5);
}
```